# Is there a USB device that will both take HDMI input and send out mouse/keyboard signals to a USB input?

Tags: usb, hdmi, remote-access

I have an Unraid server that can run headlessly most of the time, but it's occasionally useful to see video output from the server and have keyboard/mouse control for either accessing the BIOS or the Unraid terminal.

Since I want to be able to access the machine at the BIOS level, before anything like a VNC server would or could be booted up, that type of solution won't help.

I have another computer with monitor and keyboard sitting right next to the Unraid server. Rather than using a KVM, I'd like to be able to open a window on that computer which would show not only video output from that computer, but, much as VNC client would, would redirect keyboard and mouse signals to the not-so-remote server via something plugged into one of the server's USB inputs.

I currently have a USB HDMI digitizer that will let me see the video output from the server in a roundabout way, through a window meant to monitor a recording session, but that does nothing to handle sending keyboard and mouse actions.

If such a device (and the associated software) exists, I haven't figured out what to call it our how to describe it well enough to find that device by googling for it.

Comment: As I said, I can, in a kludgy way, see video even at the BIOS level without an extra monitor, by digitizing the HDMI video output over USB. The big thing lacking with that approach is sending keyboard/mouse signals back to respond to the images I can see that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Rather than using a KVM, I'd like to be able to open a window on that computer which would show not only video output from that computer, but, much as VNC client would, would redirect keyboard and mouse signals to the not-so-remote server via something plugged into one of the server's USB inputs.

That kind of product is typically called an "IP KVM" or "KVM over IP". (Not to be confused with "KVM extender".) I've been looking into getting a PiKVM, but it seems there *are* cheaper products.

Server motherboards usually have such a system built-in as part of their management controller (BMC, such as HP's "iLO" or Dell's "iDRAC") – the management controller has its own IP address and usually offers KVM through a webapp (or through a Java app if you're unlucky).

If you only need to access the bootloader (e.g. GRUB settings) and not actually BIOS settings, you could do that through a serial console ("COM port").

Comment: Thanks. Over USB would have been nice, but an IP-based solution would work too, albeit making the server require two network connections, not just one.

This is a homemade Unraid server, by the way, using a cheap motherboard (Unraid works just fine without a high-end, high-powered system), so it certainly doesn't have any special server motherboard features.